# Classifier converges to just one Class - Increase Diversity

Tags: classification, tensorflow

I want to force a classifier to not come up with the same results all the time (unsupervised, so I have no targets):

```
  max_indices = tf.argmax(result, 1)
  cross_entropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(result, max_indices, name="cross_entropy_per_example")
  cross_entropy_mean = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy, name="cross_entropy")
```

Where:

- *result* are the logits returned from inference
- *max_indices* are thus the predicted classes across all the batches (size=matchsize)
- *cross_entropy* as implemented here measures how strongly the predicted result is in fact predicted (as if measuring simply the confidence)

I then optimize to minimize that loss. Basically I want the net to predict a class as strongly as possible.

Obviously this converges to some random class and will then classify everything in that one class.

So what I want is to add a penalty to prevent all predictions in a batch to be the same. I checked the math and came up with the [Shannon Diversity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diversity_index#Shannon_index) as a good measure, but I cannot implement this in tensorflow. Any idea how to do this, either with the diversity measure stated or any substitute?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good rule of thumb is to have the loss function that reflects on what you actually want to optimize. If you want to increase the diversity, it would make sense to have your loss function actually measure diversity.

While I'm sure there's a more correct way to do it, here's one heuristic that can get you closer to the Shannon Diversity you mention:

1. Let's make a hypothesis that the output of the softmax is actually close to one for the predicted class and is close to zero for all other classes.
2. Then the proportion of each class is the sum of outputs of the softmax over the batch divided by the batch size.
3. Then the loss function that approximates the Shannon Diversity would be something along the lines of:

```py
sm = tf.softmax(result)
proportions = tf.reduce_mean(result, 0) # approximated proportion of each class
addends = proportions * tf.log(proportions) # multiplied by the log of itself
loss = tf.reduce_sum(addends) # add them up together to get the loss
```

When I think more about it, it might potentially break and instead of trying to diversify classes instead make very uncertain predictions (effectively breaking the original assumption that softmax is a good approximation for the one-hot encoding of the predicted class). To get around it I would add up together the loss I described above and your original loss from your question. The loss I described will be optimizing the approximated Shannon Diversity, while your original loss will prevent the softmax from becoming more and more uncertain.

Comment: This looks like a very promising idea. Will try tonite or tomorrow and report :-) Thx so far

Comment: Did the trick. Thx a lot. Changed to tf.reduce_mean(sm, 0) though